# cp on nfs share claims to fail but actually succeeds

Tags: linux, rhel, nfs, cp

I am dealing with an nfs share where I have read/write permissions. Everything seems to work fine, except when I copy files to subdirectories. Then the `cp` command complains that file creation was unsuccessful. When I check for the file, the copy actually took place.

```
[user@system mytest]$ touch myfile
[user@system mytest]$ mkdir mydir
[user@system mytest]$ cp myfile mydir/
cp: cannot create regular file ‘mydir/myfile’: Operation not permitted
[user@system mytest]$ ls -l mydir
total 0
-rwx------ 1 user group users 0 Sep 27 19:00 myfile
```

Rerunning the `cp` command does not trigger another error message. The `mv` command works without a problem.

Any ideas?

**strace output**

```
stat("myfolder/", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0700, st_size=4096, ...}) = 0
stat("myfile", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0700, st_size=5, ...}) = 0
stat("myfolder/myfile", 0x7ffebd019c10) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("myfile", O_RDONLY) = 3
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0700, st_size=5, ...}) = 0
open("myfolder/myfile", O_WRONLY|O_CREAT|O_EXCL, 0700) = -1 EPERM (Operation not permitted)
```

Comment: Who's the owner of the current directory and of the file, and what user and group are you running as? It could fail setting the original user/group on the file?

Comment: Have a look at the last lines of `strace cp myfile mydir/`

Comment: Thanks for the hints: Here is the output: 

stat("myfolder/", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0700, st_size=4096, ...}) = 0
stat("myfile", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0700, st_size=5, ...}) = 0
stat("myfolder/myfile", 0x7ffebd019c10) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("myfile", O_RDONLY)                = 3
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0700, st_size=5, ...}) = 0
open("myfolder/myfile", O_WRONLY|O_CREAT|O_EXCL, 0700) = -1 EPERM (Operation not permitted)

Comment: This is kinda weird behavior from NFS server. `tcpdump -i <name-of-ethernet-interface> port nfs and host <hostname-of-the server>` may shed light on this.

Comment: What is the NFS server and the underlying filesystem?  Is it Linux/EXT4? Are you using v3 or v4?  I suspect the error is saying the file was not created with the requested permissions.  If you `ls -l` the file, is it mode 700 or different?

Comment: The file is not actually copied but an empty file is created. What happens if you try to copy a non-empty file?